# Unique function assigning an integer to a finite CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

This is exercise 2.2.25 in Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf):

> Show that for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is a unique function $\varphi$ assigning an integer to each finite CW complex, such that
>
> (a) $\varphi(X) = \varphi(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, (b) $\varphi(X) = \varphi(A) + \varphi(X/A)$ if $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$, and (c) $\varphi(S^0) = n$.
>
> For such a function $\varphi$, show that $\varphi(X) = \varphi(Y)$ is $X \simeq Y$.

Playing around with it, I find that $\varphi(D^k)=0$ for any disk $D^k$ (collapse half of a sphere, leaving something homeomorphic to the sphere), and $\varphi(A \sqcup B) = \varphi(A) + \varphi(B)$. Now suppose I have $D^1 \sqcup D^1$, each disk composed of two zero cells and a one cell. I pick one zero cell from each disk, and quotient by this subcomplex, and the subcomplex is homeomorphic to $S^0$. But since the quotient is homeomorphic to a disk again, it seems the axioms cannot hold, since this gives $0 = n + 0$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $\varphi(A \sqcup B)$ is not equal to $\varphi(A) + \varphi(B)$. You didn't say how you proved that, so I can only guess, but $(A \sqcup B) / B \cong A \sqcup *$, not $A$, so you get $\varphi(A \sqcup B) = \varphi(A \sqcup *) + \varphi(B)$, and $\varphi(A \sqcup *) \neq \varphi(A)$. If $A$ is nonempty, take some point $x \in A$ and then collapse $\{x,*\} \cong S^0$ to get $\varphi(A \sqcup *) = \varphi(A) + n$, hence if $A$ is nonempty (or symmetrically if $B$ is nonempty):
$$\varphi(A \sqcup B) = \varphi(A) + \varphi(B) + n.$$

If it can help to guess how it works, notice that $\varphi(X) := n \cdot (\chi(X) - 1)$ satisfies all the conditions. It's true that $\chi(A \sqcup B) = \chi(A) + \chi(B)$, but this doesn't hold for $\varphi$ anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. If you were to prove homotopy invariance of $\varphi$, would you just piggy-back on homotopy invariance of $\chi$? I wondered if perhaps there was an elegant way without doing so, but it seems any such attempt would just reprove that cellular homology is the same as singular homology (if we define $\chi$ in terms of ranks of singular homology groups).

Comment: I don't know if there's an elegant way, maybe writing $X$ and $Y$ as deformation retract of some $Z$ and trying to do something with quotients would work? I haven't tried. Otherwise, either using the homotopy invariance of $\chi$ or reusing cellular homology would work, as you say.

Comment: How do we know that such $\phi$ is unique?